# Can't access variable in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

After rewriting a link

```
http://localhost/schoolproject/posts.php?post_id=193
```

to

```
http://localhost/schoolproject/post/193
```

I can't access variable that are appended to the URL. For example:

```
http://localhost/schoolproject/post/193/?like=true
```

How do I access the variable `like` with PHP `$_GET['like']`

I tried it but PHP tells me the variable is not set.

What is wrong here?

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ posts.php?post_id=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^post([^/]+)?$ posts.php [L,NC]
```

---

```
<?PHP 

if (isset($_GET['post_id'],$_GET['like'])) {
    echo "variables are set";
}else{
    echo "not set";
}

?>
```

Comment: `QSA` : https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA

Comment: yes! it worked... by enabling the [QSA] fag

Comment: maybe better to delete this^ and resend it, or is it a "casual way" of offending CD001 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use QSA

`RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ posts.php?post_id=$1 [QSA]`

Or if QSA doesn't work for you, you can try this hack:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ posts.php/?post_id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}  [L,NC]
```

Comment: The only time I can imagine that using `%{QUERY_STRING}` like this would be necessary is if you needed to change the order in which the query string params were applied (in which case `%{QUERY_STRING}` should be earlier/first, not _last_, as in your example). But if you do use `%{QUERY_STRING}` here, you should not use the `QSA` flag as well since the URL params from the request will simply be duplicated.

Comment: Ah! that was a typo.. corrected that. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

use QSA

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ posts.php?post_id=$1 [QSA]
```